# Avoid duplicates in polymorphic hasAndBelongsToMany through-model relation

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I have a rather complex relation with a polymorphic through-model. In the app, there is a tag system, where users and another model can be tagged. To avoid duplicate string entries, I used a through model (TagLink) which contains the tag ID, the tagged model name and the tagged instance ID.

So I have

```
User --+
       |
       +---> TagLink -----------> Tag
       |      - tagId              - id
Item --+      - taggableId         - text
              - taggableName
                (User or Item)
```

The linking relation is `hasAndBelongsToMany`. The problem is, when I post a new tag to `/items/:id/tags` or `/users/:id/tags`, it is saved, but I can create as many as I want with the same text without any error.

What I would like is, upon posting to `/items/:id/tags` or `/users/:id/tags`, it :

- creates a new tag entry if it does not already exists, then adds a new `TagLink` entry (this is the current behaviour, but even when the same tag already exists)
- solely creates a `TagLink` entry when a tag already exists

I thought about two solutions :

- Somehow override the create method of `Tag` to check for existence, then manually create a `TagLink` entry if it exists. If not, proceed as by default.
- Expose the tag list (`/tags`) with ~all CRUD URIs, then force to use the tag ID on `/{items,users}/:id/tags`.

Ideally, I would prefer the first one as it is more transparent and makes a smoother API.

So, any leads would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the first solution, which was pretty easy. The idea is to replace the `User.create` method in a boot script which finds a tag with the same `text`, and returns it if one is found.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var Tag = app.models.Tag;

    // Override Tag.create to avoid duplicates
    Tag.createRaw = Tag.create;
    Tag.create = function(data, token, cb) {
        // Find matching tag
        Tag.findOne({where: {text: data.text}}, (err, tag) => {
            if (err)      cb(err);
            // If the tag is found, return it
            else if (tag) cb(null, tag);
            // Else create it
            else          Tag.createRaw(data, token, cb);
        });
    }
}
```